# Correlations between 4 variables

Tags: correlation, expected-value, independence

I have $m_{1R}$, $m_{2R}$, $m_{1L}$, $m_{2L}$, and about them, I know that

$Corr(m_{1R}, m_{1L}) = 0$

$Corr(m_{2R}, m_{2L}) = 0$

$Corr(m_{1R}, m_{2L}) = 0$

$Corr(m_{2R}, m_{1L}) = 0$

Suppose I also know that $E[m_{1R}] > E[m_{2R}]$. What can be concluded about
$E[m_{1L}]$ vs $E[m_{2L}]$?

More specifically, I suspect that the correlation relationships from above prevent me from telling anything about the comparison between $E[m_{1L}]$ and $E[m_{2L}]$ even if I know about  $E[m_{1R}]$ vs $E[m_{2R}]$. Is this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$E[m_{1L}]$ and $E[m_{2L}]$ can be anything under the sun.

Suppose not only everything you know and supposed, but that $m_{1R}, m_{1L}, m_{2R}$, and $m_{2L}$ are independent.  Then it is still the case that $m_{1L}$, and $m_{2L}$ can have any (marginal) distributions, and therefore, $E[m_{1L}] -E[m_{2L}]$ can be anything.

Rather than saying "the correlation relationships from above prevent me from telling anything about the comparison ...", I would say "the correlation relationships from above are insufficient to tell you anything about the comparison ..."